# extract structs values into variable named as the field

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x1 Matlab struct with 5 fields ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'). Each field contains some sort of data (which doesn't really matter for my question) and I would like to extract each value out of the struct and assign it to a variable named as the field. Any idea for a code that will do it?

Comment: As simple as that: `a = yourStruct.a`. And so on for other fields.

Comment: Are you wanting to generalize this to any number of arbitrarily-named fields? It's probably better to just keep values stored in a structure, as that is better organized than a bunch of variables.

Comment: I would like to do it automatically

Comment: If you provide more info on your use case you might get a better answer - as this type of thing is generally bad practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming `s` is your structure

```
cellfun(@(x) assignin('base', x, s.(x)), fieldnames(s));
```

However, I do not see a good use-case for this as already mentioned by gnovice.

Answer (score 3):

While it is generally *not* best practice to spread data out to a bunch of variables when you already have it neatly stored in a structure, an easy way to move structure fields to variables that doesn't require hard-coding your field/variables names would be to use the [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) commands like so:

```
s = struct('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3);  % A sample structure
save('temp.mat', '-struct', 's');    % Save fields to a .mat file
clear all                            % Clear local variables (just for display purposes)
load('temp.mat');                    % Load the variables from the file
whos                                 % Display local variables

  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1                 8  double              
  b         1x1                 8  double              
  c         1x1                 8  double
```

Pro: this is very easy and works for any structure. Con: it involves moving data into and out of a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what are the variables to be created, then you can write (assuming `s` is your struct):

```
C = struct2cell(s);
[a,b,c,d,e] = C{:};
```

Otherwise, you need to create undeclared new variables while the program is running (using the `assignin` command from [@Vahe-Tshitoyan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44370489/2627163)) and that's a bad idea.